# How do i compile and use mariadb c++ Connector library in debian 10?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, mariadb, debian, beagleboneblack

Setup: Beagleboneblack, debian10, arm, mariadb v10.3.36.

Following this guide: https://mariadb.com/docs/connect/programming-languages/cpp/install/

I reach this step:

```
$ sudo install include/mariadb/* /usr/include/mariadb/
```

when executing the above command I get the following message; `install: omitting directory 'include/mariadb/conncpp'`

I ran through the rest of the Install MariaDB Connector/C++
guide, but when i try to compile my task.cpp app using:

```
$ g++ -o tasks tasks.cpp -std=c++11 -lmariadbcpp
```

following this example: https://mariadb.com/docs/connect/programming-languages/cpp/sample-app/ i get:

```
# g++ -o tasks task.cpp -std=c++11 -lmariadbcpp
task.cpp:3:10: fatal error: mariadb/conncpp.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <mariadb/conncpp.hpp>
```

The main issue is with the -lmariadbcpp i think, its not installed in the correct place or whatever. Can someone explain to me how mariadb connector-library is installed, where it resides, and how i can use it when compiling?

It might be i can't use the c++ connector with my version of mariadb, since c++ connector requires that its a "enterprise" version of maria db. However it should be able to compile/install. Please help me understand the installation process of a library in debian? ?? :)

**Update**:
After some struggle, it seems i can install the files by cd into the include directories and installing the files manually be explicitly using the file name. Atleast i think there is some progress now...

Comment: Check if the header file is correctly installed to `/usr/include/mariadb/conncpp.hpp`. Also, check whether the include paths used by `g++` contain `/usr/include` (it should, otherwise it's not going to see the header) by appending `-v` to enable verbose output from the compiler.

Comment: "The main issue is with the `-lmariadbcpp` i think" - No, this is a linker flag and it does not affect the compiler finding headers (which is done before the linking step).

Comment: After the update, i got all files installed in the usr/lib and user/include locations (?). SO now it executes/uses the gcc. Only syntax errors in the task.cpp code remains  :p

Comment: Thanks kotatsuyaki
Code errors cleared, when compiling i get error: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../libmariadbcpp.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status      Any thoughts?

Comment: I found this, but i dont see how i can utilize the info from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69766593/cmake-error-undefined-reference-when-linking-cxx-executable

Comment: Out put of:  # ldd /usr/lib/libmariadbcpp.so
        not a dynamic executable

Comment: You should just install the mariadb package that is part of Debian.  `apt-get install libmariadb-dev`.  Rather than trying to build and install it yourself.

Comment: I have done that, but doesnt help: libmariadb-dev is already the newest version (1:10.3.36-0+deb10u2).